# hide WP popup for mobile

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, wordpress, jquery-mobile

Can anyone point me in the right direction please. . . . I'm trying to disable a opt-in popup on mobile only. The pop up is using a WordPress plugin called arty popup. At present the popup functions perfectly on all desktop and ipads, the issue is on mobile the pop up close button falls off the screen, so was trying to find some code to disable it from mobile devices only.

Any pointers would be very welcome.

this is the pop up .php

```
/* /////////////////////////////////////////////// this final section generates all     the     code that is displayed on the front-end of the WP Theme \\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\ */     function arty_popup($args = array(), $content = null) { require 'inc/popup.php'; }

add_action( 'wp_head', 'arty_header' );
function arty_header() { 
global $arty_settings;
$options = $arty_settings;?>
<script src="http://jqueryjs.googlecode.com/files/jquery-1.2.6.min.js"type="text          /javascript"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready( function() {
if (document.cookie.indexOf("arty_popup_cookie1") <= 0) {

loadPopupBox();
}       


$('#wrap-out, #popupBoxClose').click( function() {
unloadPopupBox();

var c_name  =   'arty_popup_cookie';
var value   =   'arty_popup_cookie1';
var exdays  =   <?php echo $options['popup_cookie_time']; ?>;

 var exdate=new Date();
exdate.setDate(exdate.getDate() + exdays);
var c_value=escape(value) + ((exdays==null) ? "" : ";expires="+exdate.toUTCString());
document.cookie=c_name + "=" + c_value;

});

function unloadPopupBox() {
$('#popup_box').fadeOut(200);
$("#wrap-out").css({    
    "display": "none"  
}); 
}

function loadPopupBox() {
$('#popup_box').fadeIn(200);
$("#wrap-out").css({
    "background": "#000",
    "opacity": "0.7"  
});         
}


});
```

the pop up button .css

```
.btn{
color:#FFFFFF;
width:91px;
height:40px;
margin-left:10px;
font-family:"Trebuchet MS", Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
font-size:12px;
border:none;
background:url(images/btn.gif) no-repeat top;
cursor:pointer;
}
```

Comment: If it could be made to fit on a mobile screen, would that be better than getting rid of it?  If so, media queries may do the trick for you.

Comment: true, making it responsive to a mobile screen would also work. I don't have much media queries knowledge? any suggestions ?

Comment: resize the popup using @media queries in CSS.